# Java - unload media from memory

Tags: java, video, memory, memory-management

We have a JavaFX program that plays video files.  The problem we are having is that when the video file is loaded into memory and plays, it is not unloaded when the next video file plays.  The problem then is that after a certain amount of videos are played then the memory is full and the machine screeches to a screaming halt from full memory.

We have tried building a 64-bit version of the program, but with out any advantage to doing so.

Comment: We can't help you find the bug if you don't show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

Java by default uses a mark-sweep type garbage collector, not a reference counting garbage collector. That means that when you drop all your references to the old video, the video is not unloaded from memory, instead the Java runtime waits until a certain amount of memory has been used by the program before invoking the garbage collector. These parameters are set on the Java command line or are defaulted on a per-platform basis. It sounds like your Java garbage collection parameters are set too high and as a result Java does not garbage collect before it consumes all the memory in your machine.

To set the maximum amount of memory, add the following to your JAVA_OPTS environment variable prior to running your program:

```
-verbose:gc -Xmx1200m
```

The first one will tell you what's going on with the garbage collector, the second one sets the maximum amount of memory that Java will use, 1.2 gigabytes in this case. Set to some fraction of your machine's total memory, but sufficiently large so that you can load your videos into memory.

You may wish to also add

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

in order to keep garbage collection delays low. This sacrifices some amount of ultimate performance in order to prevent 10-second delays for garbage collects from time to time. Today's machines are so fast and their memories so large that for interactive programs you'll notice garbage collection delays far more than you'll notice any slowdowns imposed by G1GC.

You want to also make sure that you drop all references to the old video as soon as the new video is loaded. Otherwise if it has an accessible reference, it won't be unloaded by the garbage collector.